# How to change the values of a 2d tensor in certain rows and columns

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I have an all-zero mask tensor like this:

```
mask = torch.zeros(5,3, dtype=torch.bool)
```

Now I want to set the value of `mask` at the intersection of the following `rows` and `cols` indices to `True`:

```
rows = torch.tensor([0,2,4]) 
cols = torch.tensor([1,2])
```

I would like to produce the following result:

```
tensor([[False, True,  True ],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, True,  True ],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, True,  True ]])
```

When I try the following code, I receive an error:

```
mask[rows, cols] = True

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing tensors could not be broadcast together with shapes [3], [2]
```

How can I do that efficiently in PyTorch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need proper shape for that you can use [`torch.unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze)

```py
mask = torch.zeros(5,3, dtype=torch.bool)
mask[rows, cols.unsqueeze(1)] = True
mask
tensor([[False,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [False,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [False,  True,  True]])
```

or [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.reshape)

```py
mask[rows, cols.reshape(-1,1)] = True
mask
tensor([[False,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [False,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [False,  True,  True]])
```